SlackAPI reactions_get call returning "bad_timestamp" even though I am using the same timestamp to delete messages
This is my slackbot code which is subscribed to several events:
@app.route("/slack/events", methods=["POST"])
def slack_events():
    if not verifier.is_valid_request(request.get_data(), request.headers):
        return make_response("Invalid request", 400)

    data = request.json

    if "event" in data:
        if data["event"]["type"] == "reaction_added":
            if data["event"]["item"]["channel"] == "C07ES6K4W3K":
                reaction_count = len(slack_client.reactions_get(channel = data["event"]["item"]["channel"], ts = data["event"]["item"]["ts"])["message"]["reactions"])
                if reaction_count == 2:
                    response = slack_client.chat_delete(channel=data["event"]["item"]["channel"], ts = data["event"]["item"]["ts"])
                    return make_response("", response.status_code)

The chat_delete works fine with the same channel and timestamp but the reactions_get gives:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2077, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1525, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1523, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1509, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "/home/mlabeeb03/mysite/pr_slackbot_flask_app.py", line 30, in slack_events
    reaction_count = slack_client.reactions_get(channel = data["event"]["item"]["channel"], ts = "1723465677.545809")
  File "/home/mlabeeb03/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/client.py", line 4332, in reactions_get
    return self.api_call("reactions.get", http_verb="GET", params=kwargs)
  File "/home/mlabeeb03/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/base_client.py", line 157, in api_call
    return self._sync_send(api_url=api_url, req_args=req_args)
  File "/home/mlabeeb03/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/base_client.py", line 188, in _sync_send
    return self._urllib_api_call(
  File "/home/mlabeeb03/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/base_client.py", line 319, in _urllib_api_call
    ).validate()
  File "/home/mlabeeb03/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/slack_sdk/web/slack_response.py", line 199, in validate
    raise e.SlackApiError(message=msg, response=self)
slack_sdk.errors.SlackApiError: The request to the Slack API failed. (url: https://slack.com/api/reactions.get)
The server responded with: {'ok': False, 'error': 'bad_timestamp'}

How can I fix this error?
